# Lotus Notes Rich Text Field Elements including document links

Tags: lotus-notes, attachment, rtf, subform

I got a problem regarding a computed subform:

[image: UI view]

I want to read out everything that is below *Ganzer Verlauf*.
This includes the date, Name (blacked out in this case) and the link to the attachment.

The subform looks like this:

[image: Developer view]

`contacthistory` is the field name that I want to read out.

The name of the main form is `In_Bewerbung`, the name of the subform is `Meta_Contacthistory`.

I am creating a view that ultimately exports this as XML.
My selection in the view is:

```
SELECT (Form = "In_Bewerbung") & !@IsAvailable(DOCDELETED)& !@IsAvailable(DOCARCHIVED)
```

Here is a code snippet of a Lotus Script function that uses `contacthistory`:

[image: Lotus Script Code]

Currently, I am unable to get anything. Where do I need to start and what steps do I need to follow in order to make it work?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Contacthistory is a rich text field. You can't show the contents of a rich text field in a view.

Create a new computed field on the form and use the @Abstract formula to pull out the text of the contacthistory item.

```
@Abstract([TextOnly]; 64000; ""; ContactHistory);
```

Then use this new computed field in your view.  Note that you won't be able to show doc links in your view unfortunately.

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_ABSTRACT.html

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for the answer. I will try to implement it and get back to you. If there is no way to show the doc links, is there a way to read out the properties of $Links?

Comment: Since the $Links item is an internal one, I'm not sure it can be read like other items.  You could try a similar technique with the @Abstract formula to get the text out of that item perhaps.

Comment: $Links just point to linked documents. And links in rich text fields contain reference to index in $Links. I'm using C API from LotusScript to obtain this info. I imagine it is possible to obtain it using XML export of rich text (and parse through links)

Answer (score 0):

In "View Selection" property of your view, put `SELECT (Form = "In_Bewerbung")`
Afterwards, add `contacthistory` to `Column Value` of the column that is displayed in your view. 
This will display the information stored in `contacthistory` field, in your view.
After this you can work on your XML export.

Comment: This does not work. That's pretty much what I have right now, with the exception that there does not seem to be a field contacthistory