# Lotus Notes - In which field are links of $LINKS stored?

Tags: hyperlink, field, lotus-notes

The header says it all more or less.
In which field are the links from $LINKS stored?

Comment: This question is related to this other question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22631392/lotus-notes-rich-text-field-elements-including-document-links and does not make any sense without a link to that initial question...

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific field. Notes is schemaless and allows creation of items with any name or type, at the whim of the application developer. $Links is a reserved item name that is used to track information for doclinks created in rich text items.  Under normal circumstances (i.e., doclinks created interactively through the Notes editor or through code that uses the appropriate APIs), $Links will contain information for all doclink in all rich text items in the document.

For much more details about doclinks and $Links, please see this [blog post](http://www.geniisoft.com/showcase.nsf/archive/20030705-0202) by Ben Langhinrichs.

Comment: Is there a way for me to obtain those contents? I had a look manually and the text stored in $Links would be of value to me.

Comment: in "$Links" !? `NotesDocument.GetItemValue( "$Links" )`

Comment: Please be more precise. What, exactly, did you look at manually? How did you look at it? What exact text did you see that will be of value to you?  I'm asking because I believe that only some of the information for each doclink is stored in $Links.  (Note: I've added a link to a very infromative blog post up in my answer above.)

Comment: Manually as in the Lotus Notes Frontend. I looked at Document properties and the contents were of interest to me.
`NotesDocument.GetItemValue( "$Links" )` doesnt work in Formula language, unfortunately.

And thanks for the link, will have a look.

Comment: Okay, formula language...  You can't get much of anything there. At a minimum, you need LotusScript. And for some information, only the C API or the (3rd party) Midas API will help.  (Maybe the C++ API, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: Torsten Link is the person to ask Link questions